# How to count the number of characters in a text field dynamically in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to be able to calculate 200 - the number of characters at any time.
Meaning that I want to display the number of characters and have it update any time the user inputs or deletes characters.

The code I have properly counts 200 - the number of characters at any time but I don't know how to update the text field constantly.

```
-(void)updateLabel{
// Get the text from the message
// find the length of the text
// subtract from the converted number in the charCounter Label
// display in the charCounter Label

 int length = _message.text.length;
 int charLeft = 200 - length;
 NSString* charCountStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", charLeft];
 _charCounter.text = charCountStr;

}
```

And then I call the updateLabel function in the viewDidLoad.

I suspect that there must be some other function to persistently update the viewController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just implement the UITextFieldDelegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and call your updateLabel method from within it.

[From the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a)

> The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    [self updateLabel];

    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to set your text field's delegate property, and to make sure that your class conforms to UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: I don't fully understand. The class that I'm using is inheriting from UIViewController. What do you mean when you say conform to UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: After you do the : UIViewController inheritance, type <UITextFieldDelegate>, then in your viewdidload, set the text field's delegate to self.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want a Twitter-like dynamic count of the amount of characters that a user can type into a UITextBox. So you have a limit of 200 characters and you want to inform the user how much characters he or she typed dynamically.

If you want that method to run every time the the text changes:

```
// textField is the UITextField you type your text in to.
// this could be a reference to that field via an IBOutlet or you created it manually
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(updateLabel) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```